# Intuitve explanation for $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, intuition

So I can do a mathematical proof of $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$. But I would like a deeper, I guess more applicable, understanding.

Here's my mathematical proof:
$$(AB)^{-1}(AB) = I$$
$$(AB)^{-1}AB = I$$
$$(AB)^{-1}ABB^{-1} = IB^{-1} = B^{-1}$$
$$(AB)^{-1}AI =(AB)^{-1}A = IB^{-1} = B^{-1}$$
$$(AB)^{-1}AA^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$$
$$(AB)^{-1}= B^{-1}A^{-1}$$

I want to say that this intuitively makes sense because we need the rows and columns of both sides of the equation to equal. Let's say $A$ is a $n\ x\ k$ matrix and $B$ is a $k\ x\ n$, then $AB$ is a $n\ x\ n$ matrix and our $(AB)^{-1}$ matrix is also $n\ x\ n$.

Now, $B^{-1}$ is going to be a $n\ x\ k$ matrix while $A^{-1}$ is a $k\ x\ n$ matrix. It can't be that $(AB)^{-1} = A^{-1}B^{-1}$ because that's a $k\ x\ k$ matrix on the right.

However although this makes intuitive sense, this shouldn't hold up. B and A can't be non-square matrices because those can't have inverses. Only square matrices have inverses(non-zero determinant).

Can someone explain why $(AB)^{-1}= B^{-1}A^{-1}$ is true intuitively?

Comment: The product of a $n\times k$ matrix with an $k \times n$ matrix is an $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: Say you pass 2 bridges, bridge 1 then bridge 2. To go back, you go back through bridge 2 first then bridge 1. This is analogous with transformation

Comment: Let's say "getting dressed" means putting your socks on, then your shoes. Then getting undressed means taking off your shoes, then your socks.

Comment: The point is that the matrices correspond to transformations.

Comment: I posted an answer that I am now convinced is inappropriate.  Based on the reaction of others, I am not knowledgeable enough to provide an answer.  Therefore, I deleted my (own) answer.

Comment: "Let's say "getting dressed" means putting your socks on, then your shoes." You must live in a very warm climate.

Comment: Regarding the other questions you have: Note that the identity $(AB)^{-1}=A^{-1}B^{-1}$ holds **if and only if** $A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices (and therefore, they must be squared). For rectangular matrices, you can fiddle stuffs with pseudo inverses, but there you have to be careful.c

Answer (score 2):

For me the fact that $B^{-1}A^{-1}$ "works" as a two-sided inverse to $AB$ is both intuitive, and somewhat rigorous.

Interestingly, as far as I know, the same identity, which holds in group theory more generally, is called the "socks and shoes identity".